# PayPal API call via curl generates 81002 error

Tags: curl, paypal

I'm getting the **81002 Method Specified Not Supported error** back from the paypal API when I make this curl call:

curl -v https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{
     "USER":"xxx",
     "PWD":"xxx",
     "SIGNATURE":"xxx",
     "METHOD":"GetTransactionDetails",
     "TRANSACTIONID":"1E9110554D136853V",
     "VERSION":"94" 
     }'

I've checked that GetTransactionDetails is a valid method.  Is there something wrong with the curl call?

Thanks!

- Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NVP Endpoint for Classic APIs won't accept JSON.

You basically just send HTTP POST data to the NVP API:

curl -v https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp -d 'USER=xxxx&PWD=xxxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxx&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&TRANSACTIONID=123456789abcdef&VERSION=94'

Check out https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/ for full documentation on how PayPal handles NVP.

Further, I would highly recommend testing you API calls in the developer sandbox first.

Comment: That works! My first tries were also without JSON, but I can see from your version that my quoting was off.  THANKS!